# Azure web role recycle - would local data be lost?

Tags: azure, nuget

Am trying to host my org's nuget repository in an Azure Web role. That means, the packages are configured to be stored in a local drive (say d:\NuGetPackages) in the machine on the cloud.

The hosting works perfectly as expected, am able to push packages and download from it. However, my concern is if the VM is recycled (either manually or automatically), would that preserve my local repositories of the packages? Or is it that on recycling the whole VM is recreated and only the webrole restored, thus wiping out any other folders outside the scope of the webrole?

I can't have this folder as a part of the webrole folders (like the default package installation for NuGet is ~\packages, which would translate to the IIS folder in the webrole) as it would be overwritten on every deployment. Thus, this packages folder has to be outside somewhere. Would a FileStorage help (I'll need to check, though, if a nuget package path can accept a file storage path).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, any data on D:\ can and will at some point vanish.

Your options are either Azure Storage (including their new File service) or the older Azure CloudDrive (don't know if that's even still around, but wasn't a good option anyway).

I fear I don't really understand your use case scenario but wouldn't an Azure VM (IaaS) be a better choice here? Feels like the statelessness of a PaaS role is your main problem, so PaaS wouldn't really be a good fit

Comment: Thanks, I thought about a VM also, but then I'll need to worry about maintaining the VM too which I thought I could avoid if just using a WebRole. I'll need to explore the file storage in that regard, so that maintenance is min in that regard, else it will have to be a VM :(